# Firefox XPCOM extension not working after installation (C++)

Tags: c++, firefox, firefox-addon, gecko, protocol-handler

I have implemented a protocol handler extension in C++ using Gecko SDK. When the dll is copied to C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\components every thing works perfectly. But when the the same dll is used to create .xpi installation file, the extension gets installed; but the custom protocol did not work.

I have the following structure in the xpi file

```
chrome.manifest
components
components/abc.dll
install.rdf
```

I do not have the IDL file. Is IDL file required in xpi?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed!

Was missing `<em:unpack>true</em:unpack>` in install.rdf

Should have included install.rdf in the question :)